# How to check that rows start with or contain same value when grouped by other column in pandas

Tags: pandas, group-by, startswith

I have a dataframe that I'd like to group by id and the common 'top level' string with the count of 'lower-level' strings it includes.
For example,

```
    id name
    1  AA-BB-CC-DD
    1  AA-BB-CC
    1  AA-BB-CC-DD-EE
    1  AA-BB-UU-VV
    1  AA-BB-UU
    1  FF-MM-NN
    1  FF-MM-NN-PP
    2  XX-YY
    2  XX-ZZ
    2  XX-ZZ-AA
```

for ***id 1*** the first top level of column name is ***AA***, second ***BB***, third ***CC***, etc. The common 'highest' level for id 1 in the data frame is ***AA-BB-CC***.

The desired output is

```
    id  name      count
    1   AA-BB-CC  3
    1   AA-BB-UU  2
    1   FF-MM-NN  2
    2   XX-YY     1
    2   XX-ZZ     2
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can form groups using the first level, then `groupby.agg` using a custom function:

```
group = df['name'].str.extract('^([^-]+)', expand=False)

def min_string(s):
    return min(s, key=lambda x: x.count('-'))

out = (df
 .groupby(['id', group], as_index=False)
 .agg(name=('name', min_string),
      count=('name', 'count')
     )
)
```

output:

```
   id      name  count
0   1  AA-BB-CC      3
1   1  FF-MM-NN      2
2   2     XX-YY      3
```

##### update: handle minimal set of first level(s)

change `min_string` to:

```
def min_string(s):
    return '-'.join(x[0] for x in zip(*s.str.split('-'))
                    if len(set(x)) == 1)
```

example input:

```
   id            name
0   1     AA-BB-CC-DD
1   1        AA-BB-CC
2   1  AA-BB-CC-DD-EE
3   1     AA-BB-UU-VV
4   1        AA-BB-UU
5   1        FF-MM-NN
6   1     FF-MM-NN-PP
7   2           XX-YY
8   2           XX-ZZ
9   2        XX-ZZ-AA
```

output:

```
   id      name  count
0   1     AA-BB      5
1   1  FF-MM-NN      2
2   2        XX      3
```

##### update2: maximal common subgroup

```
def make_groups(s, sep='-'):
    d = {}
    s = s.str.split(sep).sort_values()
    prev = s.iloc[0]
    for idx, val in s.items():
        if val[:len(prev)] != prev:
            prev = val
        d[idx] = sep.join(prev)
    return pd.Series(d, index=s.index)

group = df.groupby('id', group_keys=False)['name'].apply(make_groups)

out = (df
 .groupby(['id', group], as_index=False)
 .agg(name=('name', min_string),
      count=('name', 'count')
     )
)
```

output:

```
   id      name  count
0   1  AA-BB-CC      3
1   1  AA-BB-UU      2
2   1  FF-MM-NN      2
3   2     XX-YY      1
4   2     XX-ZZ      2
```

used input:

```
   id            name
0   1     AA-BB-CC-DD
1   1        AA-BB-CC
2   1  AA-BB-CC-DD-EE
3   1     AA-BB-UU-VV
4   1        AA-BB-UU
5   1        FF-MM-NN
6   1     FF-MM-NN-PP
7   2           XX-YY
8   2           XX-ZZ
9   2        XX-ZZ-AA
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247884/discussion-between-nadiia-and-mozway).